# When IIS is stopped how to show Custom html page

Tags: iis

I want to know when the IIS is stopped can I show a custom html page instead of 404 error message? I stop IIS with help of cmd(net stop WAS ). I have tried app_offline.htm. it works fine. But when I start deploy by stopping the IIS the html page is not shown. I have searched a lot for this. But everywhere the Q is about only stopping the site. I want to know the reason why I can't show and also if there is any solution to that please help me. I am almost new in professional line. And my senior won't believe me because I can't explain why doesn't it work.

Comment: You cannot stop core services like HTTP or WAS, as that breaks all IIS functionalities. To deploy a site you just need to stop the site alone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand. Then there is no way I can handle any error when the IIS is stopped. I need to stop the specific site. And then I can show my custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

The web page is able to be showed due to that the IIS provides the hosting service. As long as the related IIS service is stopped, these web pages no longer been served.
The blog written by IIS official shows the IIS core service used to host the web page.
https://blogs.iis.net/tomwoolums/the-services-behind-internet-information-services-7-0
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.